# Passing the value of a jQuery UI Slider and Position of a Handle in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jquery-ui-slider

i'm trying jquery UI slider for edit form in my app rails. When editing object, value of object not passing to position handle look this screenshoot : http://i.cubeupload.com/UlmeEe.png and when i slide handle, value not passing into field. look this screenshoot : http://i.cubeupload.com/5UmYyz.png

in javascript, i set min : 2000 and value get from value of storage.

```
<script> 
     $( "#slider" ).slider({
       value: $('storage').val(),
       animate: true,
       range: "min",
       min: 2000,
       max: 5000,
       step: 1000,
       change: function(event, ui) {
          $('storage').val(ui.value);
          }

     });
</script>
```

in edit.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :storage, "Storage" %><br/>
    <div id="slider"></div> <br/>
        <%= f.text_field :storage %>        
  </div>
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: sorry, maybe these tutorial helped you, but it does not really help my problem.. Can you explain how the tutorial can be applied to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved..

change javascript with

```
    <script> 

         $( "#slider" ).slider({
          value: $('input#account_storage').val(),
          animate: true,
          range: "min",
          min: 2000,
          max: 5000,
          step: 1000,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "input#account_storage" ).html( ui.value );
          },

          change: function(event, ui) {
          $('input#account_storage').attr('value', ui.value);
          }
        });
   </script>
```